# In a forEach loop in typescript, how can I add to my variable through each instance?

Tags: typescript, foreach

I have a forEach loop in a function, I want to count each time that forEach loop is executed. How can I fix my logic to do that?

Here is my attempt:

```
createUIListElements(){
    xml2js.parseString(this.xml, (err, result) => {
      this.uiListElement = result['cm:property-placeholder']['cm:default-properties'][0]['UIInput'][0]['UIListElement']
      console.log(this.uiListElement);
      this.uiListElementArray = this.uiListElement.map((element: { $: any;}) => element.$);
      this.uiListElementArray.forEach((element: any) => {
        let i = 0;
        this.createUIElementsList(i);
        i = i +1;
        console.log(element);
      })
      
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let i = 0;` should be outside of `forEach` loop